# c++ bufferoverflow order of execution

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I have some troubles to understand the order of execution of a c++ program. I have a program with a bufferoverflow. But the thing that is strange is that the segfault (due to the bufferoverflow) happens in the code some lines before the bufferoverflow.

My program is as follow:

```
//Some code ...
file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
auto file_size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0);

std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(file_size);

//Some code
char t[1];
t[2] = 1;

//Some code
```

So the affectation `t[2] = 1` generates a **bufferoverflow**. But the segfault happens during the initialization of the vector. The `file_size` is well computed but when `std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(file_size)` is executed, `file_size` becomes -1 (generating a segfault). This segfault is generated by the bufferoverflow. If I removed the statement `t[2] = 1`, every works well.

So my question is how the segfault can happen before the execution of the bufferoverflow? The execution of code can be altered by the compiler?

Comment: `t[2] = 1` with a size 1 array does NOT generate a stack overflow.

Comment: `t[2] = 1` is not going to overflow the stack. It will overwrite some other stack-allocated object, which would be a *buffer overflow*, but it won't cause the stack itself to exceed its bounds. And if `file_size` is -1 when you call the vector constructor, it was returned as -1 from the call to `tellg`. So you should be looking at that.

Comment: There is a possibility that the `std::vector` can't allocate `file_size` elements.

Comment: Also a possibility that somewhere in the `// some code` something unexpected, and fortunately fatal, happens.

Comment: If your file_size value is -1, allocating a vector with a size of -1, that will be converted to an unsigned size_type of 2^^32-1 elements, is asking for trouble. Allocating too big objects can cause a segfault instead of throwing a nice exception.

Comment: @kuroineko I just said you were wrong and explained how. Didn't meant to be rude if I was.

Comment: When I wrote stackoverflow I was meaning that `t[2]=1` will overwrite some other stack-allocated object. My bad. As I said, the problem with the vector happens only when I write `t[2]=1`. Without that line, my vector is well constructed. `file_size` has the good value. The error happens only when I make the buffer-overflow. As I said, it is strange because the vector initialization is computed before the buffer-overflow.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour.  End of story.  One possible outcome would be a stack overflow in subsequent code.  By the way @José you were not rude.  You were being objective.

Comment: @paddy. Rude and objective are not mutually exclusive. You can even be rude, subjective and prying uninvited into a discussion all at the same time. Besides, understanding what lies beyond an UB can be quite educational IMO.

Comment: @kuroineko This is a public forum, and expressing one's opinion in a public discussion is not "prying".  I don't expect to be jumped on for providing my opinion that Jose was being objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is how the segfault can happen before the execution of the bufferoverflow? The execution of code can be altered by the compiler?

The compiler is free to rearrange initialisation of unrelated data on the stack. There is no logical relationship between your vector and the array, and so the compiler can decide to reorder the initialisation if it chooses.

But you have invoked undefined behaviour by overflowing your array bounds.  That means you have violated any assumptions made by the compiler about how it can reorder memory or code.  So all bets are now off.  Anything can happen, even if it doesn't make sense.